# Каков аналог futex Linux в Windows?

Tags: c, многопоточность, ос

Я знаю,что в Linux есть futex.Но какой ближайший аналог этого в Win32 API?

Comment: futex - это внутренняя реализация мютекса. Поэтому ответ - мютекс - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-mutex-objects   либо уточняйте вопрос.

Comment: Я сейчас зашел на английскую википедию и там говорится,что фьютексы были реализованы в Microsoft Windows начиная с Windows 8 или Windows Server 2012 под названием WaitOnAddress